# how to calculate the Inverse of the normal cumulative distribution function (cdf) using scala breeze?

Tags: apache-spark, breeze, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, scala-breeze

I would like to calculate Inverse of the normal cumulative distribution function (cdf) using scala breeze similar to MATLAB function NORMINV. But i did not find any builtin function to calculate it. could anybody has any ideas to do it in scala?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

This code solve my problem. "NormalDistribution" class gives same result as MATLAB function NORMINV.

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution
val standardNormal = new NormalDistribution(0, 1);
val infNorm = standardNormal.inverseCumulativeProbability(x)
```

Comment: If I have an sbt project then what library dependency should I add to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

SBT dependency:
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-math3" % "3.6.1"